# How do I call sets of PHP variables with a function?

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to call a set of php5 variables into another page with a function but when I ran the code, it's generating a page error. Below are my code:

```
<?php function SocialLinks(){ 
$blogger_icon   = $this->params->get('blogger_icon');
$digg_icon  = $this->params->get('digg_icon');
$facebook_icon  = $this->params->get('facebook_icon');
$stumble_icon   = $this->params->get('stumble_icon');}?>


<?php SocialLinks();//code to call my function in another page ?>
```

Please can someone tell me ho to go about this?

Comment: Can you please share the error that is returned ?

Comment: Are you including the file with the function before calling it?

Comment: It shows "500 Internal server" error on my google chrome @Nirnae
I included the file before calling it.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you call the function SocialLinks() and the variables get assigned **inside** the function. But they are not accessible outside of the function.

If you want to use the variables outside of the function, you need to return their content. For exmple:

```
class SocialLinks{
    private $bloggerIcon;
    private $diggIcon;
    private $facebookIcon;
    private $stumbleIcon;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->bloggerIcon = $this->params->get('blogger_icon'); 
        $this->diggIcon = $this->params->get('digg_icon');
        $this->facebookIcon = $this->params->get('facebook_icon');
        $this->stumbleIcon = $this->params->get('stumble_icon');
    }

    public function getBloggerIcon(){
        return $this->bloggerIcon;
    }

    public function getDiggIcon(){
        return $this->diggIcon;
    }

    public function getFacebookIcon(){
        return $this->facebookIcon;
    }

    public function getStumbleIcon(){
        return $this->stumbleIcon;
    }
}
```

Then in the other Page:

```
$socialLinks = new SocialLinks();
$socialLinks->getBloggerIcon(); //return the blogger icon
```

Comment: I'm not too good in PHP but I think this is contrary to what I'm asking.
I'm building a joomla! template, I only want to use the above variables to pull links from the templateDetails.xml file.
The variables works perfectly but I only want to call them from another page because they're very many to make the index.php clean to load fast.

Answer (score 0):

Use JFactory to get to the template parameters when you need them:

```
$params = JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate(true)->params;
```

The you can access the data you need.

```
$bloggerIcon = $params->get('blogger_icon');
```